# How to assign all the print statement from one Python class to another class inside a variable

Tags: python-3.x

I need to capture the complete output of Python class A to a variable in class B. If I try to print variable in class B, it should show the complete content of print output from class A.

I am a novice to Python programming and did the following to capture the output. In class B, I did the following:

```
import classA

printData = classA.invokeMethod()// this is main method in classA and generates huge print output
```

but 'printData' variable shows 'None' on printing. I can't modify the class A to have a return statement.

Comment: You can't easily "capture" writes to stdout. If you _absolutely must_ retrieve output from print statements, you'll likely need to run a script as a [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html) and capture its output.

Comment: If you are a novice then whatever problem you are actually trying to solve, this is probably the wrong way to do it. There are certain cases where capturing print output is required, but they are unusual, and when a novice thinks they need to do this it is almost always an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Thanks Brian and Kaya3, I understand maybe i am wrong somewhere but my requirement is without modifying class A , how to capture its output in some other class variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider classA.py that contains `class classA()`:

That class has a print wrapper style method `my_print()` which appends the data passed to it to a python list called `my_list` AFTER ALSO sending the very same data to the `print()` function.

It also has method `invokeMethod()` which produces data to be printed and (in this solution) appended to the list.  Method `invokeMethod()`returns the constructed list (in this case, 3 different types of test data - list, string, float) to the caller:

```
class classA():

    my_list = []

    def my_print(self, data_i_want_to_print):
        print('In classA:: data_i_want_to_print:', data_i_want_to_print)
        self.my_list.append(data_i_want_to_print)

    def invokeMethod(self):
        # test data item 1
        test_data = ['a','b','c']
        self.my_print(test_data)

        # test data item 2
        test_data = 'Hello, World!'
        self.my_print(test_data)

        # test data item 3
        test_data = 52.9
        self.my_print(test_data)

        print('In classA:: my_list:', self.my_list)
        return self.my_list
```

Now consider classB.py (in same directory as classA.py) that contains `class classB()` which imports classA:

When main instantiates a `classB()` instance, `classB()` instantiates a `classA()` instance which exposes `classA().invokeMethod()`.  When invoked, that method returns the class list variable built in `classA()` (known as `my_list` in `classA()`) to the `classB()` class variable `data_list`.

Main is returned the object of the `classB()` instance which exposes `classB().get_data()`.  When invoked, that method returns the `classB()` class variable `data_list` to main.

This demonstrates assignment of all print statements from one Python class to another class inside a variable.

As requested, it does capture the complete output of Python class A -->to a variable in class B.

To be clear, if you use the `my_print()` method to wrap the printing in `classA()` then you will have access to that complete data set in `classB()`.

A healthy dose of print statements were included to help the narrative along:

```
from classA import *

class classB():

    data_list = []

    def __init__(self):
        classA_instance = classA()
        self.data_list = classA_instance.invokeMethod()
        print('In classB:: data_list:',self.data_list)

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data_list

classB_instance = classB()
data_list2 = classB_instance.get_data()
print('In main:: data_list2:',data_list2)
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott for the details. This would have definitely helped but it required class A minor modification by introducing a list to capture which I am not allowed.

Comment: When you stated, "I can't modify the class A to have a return statement." I thought you meant that you "can't" because you do not know or understand how.  That's why I provided so much explanatory detail in the explanation.

Comment: Are you allowed to write to a file?  If so, instead of appending to a list in wrapper function in classA, append to a file and close it, then open that file in classB and you'll have your data.  Similarly, import sqlite3 module to store the data to a database file and you'll have your data accessible in classB.

Comment: I will discuss the different approach as guided, the list approach is elegant, let me discuss and once they allow I will accept your answer Scott.Thanks

Comment: As Scott has detailed to create a list(add all to it) and finally return that to another class and capture it as a variable in another class, I was allowed to tweak class A with minimal modification without impacting the logic. Thanks to all for your help.l